# How to return an object with a collection instead of just the collection from a Web API?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

At the moment, in my controller's service method `GetSubAccounts(accountId)`, I have this:

```cs
Account account = await context.Accounts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == accountId);
IQueryable<Account> subAccounts = context.Accounts.Include(x => x.AccountCodes).AsNoTracking();

return await mapper.ProjectTo<SubAccountViewModel>(subAccounts, null, x => x.SubAccounts)
    .Where(x => x.PersonId == account.PersonId && x.AccountId != null).ToListAsync();
```

My SubAccountViewModel is as follows: (note that it has a collection of itself)

```cs
public class SubAccountViewModel : Base.AccountViewModel
{
    public virtual ICollection<AccountCodeViewModel> AccountCodes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubAccountViewModel> SubAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping profile is:

```cs
internal class SubAccountMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public SubAccountMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Account, SubAccountViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.AccountCodes, options => options.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(x => x.SubAccounts, options => options.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

And this is the JSON I'm getting as a result:

```js
[
    {
        "id":"c236718f-9d91-4eea-91ee-66760a716343",
        "personId":"06d3857d-6a49-4e1c-b63c-7edc83d30cbd",
        "accountId":null,
        "username":"test same person",
        "email":"testsameperson@gmail.com",
        "birthDate":"2021-01-02",
        "subaccounts":null
    }
]
```

The problem:

I'm getting a top-level array of subaccounts for the `accountId` parameter I pass to the method. Fine. (There's just one, but nevermind that.)

What I ***do*** want is the main account at top-level, with the array of subaccounts as part of it.

I.e.

```js
{
    "id":"f61fedc2-eb60-4ba9-9d17-8d41b9cae9f1",
    "personId":"06d3857d-6a49-4e1c-b63c-7edc83d30cbd",
    "accountId":"f61fedc2-eb60-4ba9-9d17-8d41b9cae9f1",
    "username":"test person",
    "email":"testperson@gmail.com",
    "birthDate":"2021-01-01",
    "subaccounts":[
        {
            "id":"c236718f-9d91-4eea-91ee-66760a716343",
            "personId":"06d3857d-6a49-4e1c-b63c-7edc83d30cbd",
            "accountId":"f61fedc2-eb60-4ba9-9d17-8d41b9cae9f1",
            "username":"test same person",
            "email":"testsameperson@gmail.com",
            "birthDate":"2021-01-02",
            "subaccounts":null
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: In the first code block, the second line variable seems to be incorrect ??   as `AccountCodes` instead of `SubAccounts ` ?

Comment: @AjeetKumar No, because `AccountCodes` is also a collection of `SubAccountViewModel` (see the `SubAccountViewModel` definition in the second block of code). SubAccounts are of the same type as main accounts, this is what complicates things. I need to `.Include()`the `AccountCodes` in the query otherwise it will map to `null`.

Comment: Have you tried without automapper?

Comment: @AjeetKumar No.

Comment: Pls give it a go

Comment: I don't think AutoMapper has anything to do with this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was one of logic.

To start with, my service method (and my API controller) was returning `Task<IEnumerable<SubAccountViewModel>>`, when it should return `Task<SubAccountViewModel>`.

Then my solution was:

```cs
Account account = await context.Accounts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == accountId);
            
IQueryable<Account> accounts = context.Accounts.AsNoTracking();

SubAccountViewModel subAccountViewModel = await mapper.ProjectTo<SubAccountViewModel>(accounts, null, x => x.AccountCodes)
.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == accountId);

subAccountViewModel.SubAccounts = await mapper.ProjectTo<SubAccountViewModel>(accounts, null, x => x.AccountCodes, x => x.SubAccounts)
    .Where(x => x.PersonId == account.PersonId && x.AccountId != null).ToListAsync();

return subAccountViewModel;
```

This returns the resultset I wanted.